# Application crashes even when using a try..catch block

Tags: c#, c++, debugging

I have an application in C++ and C# (both of them in the same project). In some scenario (not reproducible every time) the application crashes and I can't see any reason to this crash.

I added a try..catch block to every place that can cause the crash - I even added a try..catch to the 'Program.cs' code that should catch the exception - and nothing helps.

How can I find the problem? Where should I start?

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is on the fritz.  You may want to try actually including some information about your code...or the error...or, well, ***anything***, really -- it's not like you could provide *less* info at this point...

Comment: Please add code. we are not god.

Comment: i dont have the error - this is something that can't reproduce on my machine

Comment: One thing that can be done is handle the "AppDomain" and Winform "Excecption" handlers. The exception could be coming from an outside control, for instance. It still might not catch the exception ... bit it *could* :)

Comment: Try hooking to AppDomains event on application exit. Hope it should tell you some thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) with the -ma, -e, -t options. When the app crashes, it should generate a dump file. Open it in your favorite debugger (VS2010 or WinDbg). Then check the call stack for clues.

Comment: but the machine that cause the crash does not have any develop envurment and i'm not allow to setup any of it. Does the procdump can work as single application ?

Comment: Yep. It's a small tool. Once you have the dump file, just copy it into your dev machine and do the analysis from there. You will only get a readable call stack though if you have the correct symbols. So for every build you release, make sure to backup your PDBs in some place (or better yet, have a symbol server).

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug (not run) application and It will find the bugs in your app.
If you are using Visual Studio 2010 Press F5.

Comment: A debugger makes it more likely, but *not certain*, to find *certain types* of bugs.  But if this happens to be a race condition, for example, debugging would be useless -- the very act of attaching a debugger can throw off the timing.

Comment: If it is not reproducible on his machine, and only intermitantly on a client how would this help him.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a log manager. At every point of execution (such as starting and end of a function), write information to a .txt file or to database. Of course, you can find where the problem is.

Comment: i have logger - and i also add the " catch(Exception ex) " - but this is still does not helping.

Comment: @Yanshof Whats the crash message you get? Does it say anything special ?